# Mac Excel web query not working

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-web-query

We use `web queries` to retrieve data in Excel for reporting purpose. These Web queries are working correctly in Excel 2007, 2010, 2013 and 2016.
But when used in **Mac Excel 2016 it fails**.

We perform these web queries using `VBA` and retrieve data generated by a `Spring REST` interface.

I already tried using `http GET` instead of `http POST` and tried performing the web query via the UI ('Data' -> 'Get External Data' -> 'Run  Saved Query' using a `.iqy` file).
Also error seems not to be content related *(tried very simple html; `<html><body><table><tr><td>col1</td></tr><tr><td>value1</td></tr></table></body></html>`)*.

When using Wireshark to analyze the traffic, the response of the REST call is correct (`http 200` with correct content).

Errors reported using UI import using '.iqy' file: `"cannot locate the internet server or proxy server"`.
Error performing web query using VBA: `"Error 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error"`.

Does anyone have an idea what can cause this behavior?

Comment: This answer *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652648/launch-a-google-search-from-vba-macro-on-mac/42652997#42652997

Comment: Thanks @CallumDA; It does not help since it does not answer performing web query calls. This has nothing to do with internet searches; `web queries` is a technique for Excel to insert sheet data from a web endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason: Spring MVC (REST) has some [default headers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html) it sets. One of them is `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`. The way we generated some of the REST response data, resulted in not setting the `Content-Type` header.

Mac Excel was not able to determine the content type *(because of the X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff option)*.

This can be solved by either not setting the [X-Content-Type-Options](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/headers.html#headers-content-type-options) header or explicitly set the `Content-Type` header.

*Bonus info*: I've used [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) to simulate REST interface and was able to strip headers one by one exposing the culprit.